# Which service to embed a videochat easily on a website?

Tags: api, video, chat, videochat

I'm working on a new website and I'd like to add a videochat feature. So I'm looking for services giving an API to do that easily.

Here is the list of features I need:

- 1-to-1 chat (a user can chat with an other one)
- video
- voice
- chat
- be able to know if somebody is currently chatting
- user-friendly
- working on all standard configurations (for example ooVoo doesn't work on safari 64bit)

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you're still looking for an answer, but http://www.tokbox.com/ looks pretty awesome for this

Comment: Without wishing to post a pointless, message, I've used tokbox and it's excellent. Worth a look.

Comment: @LeonardChallis is tokbox free?

Comment: It's actually just about to change - so the best place to consult would be this: http://static.opentok.com/pdf/OpenTok-Pricing-130829.pdf