# Cross browser audio/video chat

Tags: html, webrtc

I need to implement some kind of audio/video chat.

Customer wants maximal cross browser compatibility (ChromeFrame is not an option).

I've read about WebRTC, it's new and cool, works in Chrome and Firefox, but IE is problem.

Any ideas on implementing this chat for IE ?

Answer (score 0):

[WebRTC is not well supported](http://caniuse.com/rtcpeerconnection), thus it is not "maximally cross browser compatible".

For maximum compatibility you'll need to either write a browser plugin or use Flash.  The fact Google Hangouts [require a plugin download](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1216376?hl=en) is a pretty good indication that this is probably the best solution for supporting the maximum number of users.  But it's also non-trivial.

Honestly, implementing audio/video chat from scratch is hard.  Really hard.  So you should probably avoid it.  Instead, consider using a third party solution that you can embed.  Assuming that's the route you want to go, you should probably head over to [Which service to embed a videochat easily on a website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710280/which-service-to-embed-a-videochat-easily-on-a-website) .

Comment: WebRTC is fully supported and interoperable on Chrome, Firefox and Opera on desktop, and Chrome and Firefox on mobile  (with some pretty minor API differences: see http://goo.gl/8zPQt2) so 'not well supported' is a bit strong. According to gs.statcounter.com this equates to 61.2% of browsers, and the number is rising. Given that this means over 1.2 billion WebRTC endpoints, and much larger numbers predicted for the near future (see http://goo.gl/gFbYtt) it will be interesting to see what happens with IE and Safari. BTW Tokbox, reocommended on the Stack Overflow page you link to, uses WebRTC.

Comment: What "well supported" means is certainly debatable.  It mostly depends on what's acceptable to the OP's client.  If they're okay with 35-40% of users not having chat support then WebRTC is fine.     I do agree that WebRTC is the way forward.  This question about support just reinforces why the OP shouldn't try to do their own implementation - the landscape is changing so it's better to focus on a near-term solution that doesn't burn a lot of time or money, and revisit the issue in 12-18 months when things have changed.